# How to create a wrap in python of two functions?

Tags: python, wrapper

I have two functions.
The first will build a coder to Caesar cipher a given text:

```
def buildCoder(shift):

        lettersU=string.ascii_uppercase
        lettersL=string.ascii_lowercase
        dic={}
        dic2={}

        for i in range(0,len(lettersU and lettersL)):
            dic[lettersU[i]]=lettersU[(i+shift)%len(lettersU)]
            dic2[lettersL[i]]=lettersL[(i+shift)%len(lettersL)]
        dic.update(dic2)
        return dic
```

The second will apply the coder to a given text:

```
def applyCoder(text, coder):
        cipherText=''
        for l in text:
            if l in coder:
                l=coder[l]
            cipherText+=l
        return cipherText
```

Part 3 of the problem asks me to build a wrapper, but as I am new to coding I have no idea how to code a wrapper that uses these two functions.

```
def applyShift(text, shift):
  """
  Given a text, returns a new text Caesar shifted by the given shift
  offset. Lower case letters should remain lower case, upper case
  letters should remain upper case, and all other punctuation should
  stay as it is.

  text: string to apply the shift to
  shift: amount to shift the text (0 <= int < 26)
  returns: text after being shifted by specified amount.
  """
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of each of your functions as something that takes a certain kind of data and gives you a different kind.

`buildCoder` takes a `shift` and gives you a `coder`.

`applyCoder` takes some `text` (a string to be coded) and a `coder` and gives you the coded string.

Now, you want to write `applyShift`, a function that takes a `shift` and some `text` and gives you the coded string.

Where can you get the coded string?  Only from `applyCoder`.  It needs `text` and a `coder`.  We have the `text` because it was given to us, but we also need a `coder`.  So let's get the `coder` from `buildCoder` using the `shift` that we were provided.

Taken together, this will look like:

```
def applyShift(text, shift):
  # Get our coder using buildCoder and shift
  coder = buildCoder(shift)
  # Now get our coded string using coder and text
  coded_text = applyCoder(text, coder)
  # We have our coded text!  Let's return it:
  return coded_text
```

Comment: my GOD! I can't believe it was so simple I guessed it could be simple as the score for this part was only 5.0 points while the other two were 15 points but never I think I got overwelmed by the term wrapper more than the code itself I had done the first part of it but I was thinking of shift=buildCoder(shift) and text=applyCoder(text, coder) but was not working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the term "wrapper". Simply write another [function](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) that makes a call to the other two, and returns the result. You already got the function signature (its name and its arguments) and a description of the desired result. So in the function body do this:

1. Call `buildCoder()` with the `shift` argument and store the result in a variable `coder`
2. Call `applyCoder()` with the arguments `text` and `coder` which you just stored, and store the result in `cipher_text`
3. Return `cipher_text`

To test that your function works, write some test code that runs your `applyShift` with some sample data, for example:

```
print applyShift('Loremp Ipsum.', 13)
```

Comment: Thank you mate! you both had it cleared for me I think as I said over though about the term wrapper... and did not find useful information like the ones you have provided me!

Answer (score 0):

```
def applyShift(text, shift):
    return applyCoder(text, buildCoder(shift))
```